# Unable to use "as" selector in Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin

We have a group of vertices labeled as AGENTS, which are connected to CUSTOMERS vertices via 'SERVES' edge. Each agent node has a "ID" property.

I am looking to build a statement which counts the number of customers served by each agent by running something along the lines of:

```
g.V().has('AGENTS','STATUS','A').as('a').out().as('b').groupCount().by('ID');
```

However, I face the following error:

```
 "Gremlin step not supported. Error Name: TGQueryStepNotSupported Error Code: 8103".
```

After testing further, I have narrowed down the issue to some error in labeling the traversal appropriately.

For example, this works :

```
g.V().has('AGENTS','STATUS','A').out().limit(1);
```

However, this does not:

```
g.V().has('AGENTS','STATUS','A').as('a').out().limit(1);
```

and returns the following

```
"Gremlin step not supported. Error Name: TGQueryStepNotSupported Error Code: 8103".
```

Possible to receive some guidance?

Many thanks!

Comment: What graph system do you use? Does the TG in TGQuery stand for TigerGraph?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My apologies. I am using Tibco Graph Database, community edition. TG here stands for Tibco Graph I assume.

Comment: I think you will need to ask the database provider for help. The `as` step is rather fundamental to Gremlin. Perhaps they can suggest alternatives that they do support or let you know if they plan to add support for `as`.